# Looking for a tutorial or instructions for stored procedure calls in Mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am looking for instructions on how to run a procedure call on mysql. I have to know from very beginning what tool to use.

I hope some one could help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are quite a few at [mysqltutorial.org](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx). What you can't get from there seems pretty clear in the [CALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/call.html) page of the MySQL docs.